# How to access to Internal class converter in another assembly from XAML with "InternalsVisibleTo"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have something like this
[converter](https://www.dotnetforall.com/wpf-using-ivalueconverter-code-example/) with the difference that class is internal and for security the converter belongs to another assembly (MyAssembly.dll):

```
namespace MyAssembly.InAnotherNameSpace
{
    internal class ValueConvertor : IValueConverter
        {        
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                ...
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                ....
            }
        }
}
```

And I use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to access the converter from a WPF project:

```
....
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.InAnotherNameSpace;assembly=MyAssembly"
....
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <c:ValueConvertor x:Key="valueConvertor"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

I have a problem in XAML, not recognize the class as internal and Visual Studio show this error:

```
Only public or internal classes can be used within markup. 'ValueConvertor' type is not public or internal.
```

Follow this answer [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178579/set-ddatacontext-to-an-internal-class-of-another-assembly?answertab=active#tab-top), InternalsVisibleTo not working in XAML, that is true?

Comment: Why should it not be true, taking that fact into account that you experience the same problem?

Comment: @Clemens Because in that answer thread Ângelo Moreira asking: "Are you saying, that InternalsVisibleTo works only for C# but not for XAML?" and nobody affirms if it is true or false, so I suspect that nobody knows the answer, or is a WPF bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply a workaround - create converter in control code-behind and use it from XAML markup:

```
public partial class View : UserControl
{
    public static readonly IValueConverter valueConvertor = new MyAssembly.InAnotherNameSpace.ValueConvertor();

    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Something, Converter={x:Static local:View.valueConvertor}}"/>
```

Comment: Ok, so I must create public copy properties, because XAML only working with public properties. Nice solution, thank you!.

Comment: @Ejrr1085, note that I used *static* field, which can be accessed via `{x:Static}` extension. Instance properties will require binding, which is not supported inside `{Binding}` expression. And yes, they have to be public.

Comment: Or you can use `Converter={DynamicResource valueConvertor}` and add converter to control Resources in code-behind, or anywhere really

Comment: Thank you very match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an internal class in another assembly with InternalsVisibleTo(). Confirmed it with VS2019 and .net 4.7.2.

The VS2019 XAML editor complains throws a few errors but runs just fine.

- XDG0009 - The type "UserControl1" is not accessible.)
- XLS0419 - Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'WpfControlLibrary2' that could not be found

This seems just a limitation of VS XAML Editor.