# Error in XAML: MC3064 Only public or internal classes can be used within markup. 'S' type is not public or internal

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewmodel, visual-studio-2022

There are a few questions and answers re the error in subject, on SO, but I gather from them that the problem might be specific to the version of Visual Studio used. In my case it is VS 2022.
The solution that I work with contains several class library projects. Some classes reside in one of them, as `internal`, which should satisfy the XAML but it does not and raises this misleadingly sounding error. They are exposed in the viewmodels that reside in the same project as the WPF GUI, as `public ObservableCollection` properties.
The project that the classes are contained in is `InternalsVisibleTo`, and like in other questions, it works perfectly fine in C# but not in XAML.
If I change all of the classes to `public` then the binding works, but there is a catch:

When I bind a nested collection of those classes to a `TreeView`, then the parent level works, probably because there is no need to specify `DataType="{x:Type ...}"` that is necessary on child levels. If I remove hierarchical data templates then I have a working WPF application with only the parent level in the `TreeView`. The error is thrown only from the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the parent level, i.e. the same class that works fine w/o templates.

So, today, in 2024 and with VS 2022 updated to the latest, is there any way to bind to internal classes that are items in public collection properties of a viewmodel?

I even disassembled `PresentationFramework.dll` to see which namespaces it uses and tried to add `InternalsVisibleTo` to it, but it did not help. The error may have been hardcoded in VS.

Just to illustrate the error location in XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeViewA" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding A}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:S}" ItemsSource="{Binding T}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding Desc}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The error is thrown on the 3d line of the XAML above. Class `S` is the one that resides in another library project in the solution the owner of the solution wants to keep `internal` to prevent the general public from using the assembly outside of the solution. `A` is an `ObservableCollection<S>` and a public property of the viewmodel.
To check the theory that it might be erroring on the child type `T` I split that line in two but the error stayed on the same line, so I have to assume that it is about type `S`.

As suggested in the comment, posting C#:

Viewmodel:

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<S>? A {get;set}
}
```

Model:

```
internal class S
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<T> Ts {get;set;}
}
```

etc. down to 2 nested levels. I skipped notify implementation as they have no bearing on the question.

Comment: Hi,@Faqit. Could you show a complete code example with steps to reproduce the issue?  Can you share the error screenshot in the case of the `Public` modifier?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT Are you from Microsoft?

Comment: Hi,@Faqit. You could only bind to public properties, sub-properties and indexers or any CLR object. (quto MSDN:[Binding sources overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview?view=netdesktop-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) )
Presumably / speculatively, the reason for this is that internals can only be accessed within the same assembly and not from outside. Binding to internals doesn't work because binding is resolved by the WPF binding engine which is in a separate assembly PresentationFramework.dll.

Comment: MSDN reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx
As quoted in the reference

The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation.

Comment: You can also refer to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496177/how-to-access-to-internal-class-converter-in-another-assembly-from-xaml-with-in) to see if it helps.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT Another misleading error.